# Java - Retrieve image on the server side

Tags: java, image, server-side

I am trying to retrieve an image to display in a PDF (this is on the server side). However, no mater what path I try I get a null pointer exception. The code is:

```
try {
        //Option 1
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        System.out.println("Image path 1");
        String path = classLoader.getResource("Image/1stER_icon_256.png").getPath();
        //String path = classLoader.getResource("/Image/1stER_icon_256.png").getPath();
        //String path = classLoader.getResource("war/Image/1stER_icon_256.png").getPath();
        //String path = classLoader.getResource("/war/Image/1stER_icon_256.png").getPath();
        System.out.println("Image path = " + path);
        Image image1 = Image.getInstance(path);

        preface.add(image1);
        document.add(preface);
    } catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

And the error is:

```
Image path 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have tried other examples from my search; however, they all have code exceptions.

Comment: where is this code running? On the server? Is it a web application?

Comment: if code is runnig on server (servlet)  you need to do  servletContext.getResource("/images/picture.jpg");

Comment: Hi Jekin,  this solution has a code error "servletContext can not be resolved". How do I define servletContext please? Kind regards, Glyn

Comment: Hi Scary, the code is on the server side. I am testing on my laptop before deploying to the server. Yes, this is a web application. On the client side the user selects a person. The person's id is passed back to the server side to create the PDF. Thank you for your help, Glyn

Comment: I have searched high and low and tried may things; however, I can not get this path.